# Select2 Multiple select boxes not working

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2, laravel-5.4

I am using Select2 as part of a laravel project.  The problem I am having is that it is not responding.  Here is a picture.[image]

It is the schools box.  This does not look right.  Below is my code.

```
{{ Form::label('schools', 'Schools:') }}
                  <select class="form-control multi" name="schools"    multiple="multiple">
                          @foreach($schools as $school)
                            <option value='{{ $school->id }}'>{{ $school->name }}</option>
                          @endforeach
          </select>




          {{ form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
          {{ form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}

          {{ form::submit('Create New Member', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;')) }}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
  </div>

   @endsection

   @section('scripts')

   {!! Html::script('js/parsley.min.js') !!}
   {!! Html::script('js/select2.min.js') !!}

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.multi').select2();
   </script>
```

Comment: call select2 inside document.ready

Comment: Where is `@section('scripts')` being added to the response output (e.g., within the html page structure)? Is it in `<head>`? Or in the bottom, near `</body>`? If it's anywhere before the `.multi` elements are at, you have to wrap it in a `window.onload` or `document.ondomready` event handler (the latter has various forms in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Aravindh Gopi's suggestion?
Replace your script tag this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.multi').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Make sure that the script above written right before the body close tag